# How to do error handling for the event $translateChangeSuccess?

Tags: angularjs, localization, internationalization, angular-translate

I register the `$translateChangeSuccess` event inside a controller (upon instantiating controller).

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
    console.log("It entered translateChangeSuccess");
    A = $translate.instant('aaa');
    B = $translate.instant('bbb');
});
```

So 98% of the time the event does fire after during / after controller instantiated. But roughly 2% of the time I strongly believe the event is emitting before the controller is instantiating (i.e. to register event). So using $translateChangeSuccess event is unreliable.

What can I do to avoid this? How can I make the event to fire everytime without fail?

Comment: What are you going to do there in `$translateChangeSuccess`?

Comment: @JaganathanBantheswaran Hi, i have updated the code. im doing translation in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the above-mentioned condition. Because the `$translateChangeSuccess` would be fired whenever there is a change in translation culture (locale) regardless of whether your controller is initiated or not.

`$translateChangeSuccess` will start executing the listeners registered already for this event and will not wait until your controller gets initiated and register your listener.

And, if the `$translateChangeSuccess` fired already before your controller gets initiated, means that there is no change in the culture/locale. so your translation statements will produce the output with the latest culture/locale applied.

So in your controller's constructor or init function, you can have something like this,

```
function init() {

   translate(); // execute this because $translateChangeSuccess might have fired already.

   $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
       console.log("It entered translateChangeSuccess");
       translate();
   });

}

function translate() { 
    A = $translate.instant('aaa');
    B = $translate.instant('bbb');
}
```